# SQL server in memory table performace

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, in-memory-database, in-memory-tables

I am using Microsft SQL Server 2016. I have an SQL table with 140000 rows. It is used only for selecting data.

I am trying to increase it's selection performance by making it In-Memory table (it is worth to mention that this is my first time using In-Memory tables).

The results I am getting in SQL Server profiler are rather dissatisfying. Compared data of 'CPU', 'Reads' and 'Duration' columns: SELECT from In-Memory table has 'CPU' a bit higher, 'Reads' up to 10 times lower but unfortunately 'Duration' stays pretty much the same.

Could You please tell me if this is a good use of SQL server In-Memory tables?

Maybe I am doing something wrong since duration stays the same?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Did you tried this links to chekc whether your table is good candidate for InMemory Oltp:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/determining-if-a-table-or-stored-procedure-should-be-ported-to-in-memory-oltp#generating-in-memory-oltp-migration-checklists

Comment: Yes, I did try this and all validation results were successful.